# What is stopping this function from accepting an lvalue?

Tags: c++

`auto&&` is supposed to be like `T&&` in templates, in the sense that it means a universal reference, not an R-value reference. However, this function can only be called if I cast to an r-value. The following is taken from a JSON library I'm using:

```
#include <variant>

struct json_t
{
    using array_t = std::vector<json_t>;
    using object_t = std::map<std::string, json_t, std::less<>>;
    using null_t = std::nullptr_t;
    using val_t = std::variant<null_t, double, std::string, bool, array_t, object_t>;
    val_t data{};


    json_t& operator[](std::integral auto&& index) { return std::get<array_t>(data)[index]; }

};

int main()
{

    int lvalue = 1;

    json_t f;
    f[1]; // WORKS
    f[lvalue]; // DOESN'T WORK
    f[std::move(lvalue)]; // DOES WORK
}
```

It works if I cast to an r-value. It also works if I remove the `std::integral` from the argument signature of the `[]` function/operator. What is happening here?

The error I get is:

> no operator "[]" matches these operands

Comment: Can you explain in terms of specific error messages?

Answer (score 5):

When passing an `int` lvalue `auto` is deduced to `int&`, which doesn't satisfy the `std::integral` concept since it is a reference type, not an integral type.

With an `int` rvalue reference `auto` is deduced to just `int` which satisfies the concept.

This is always how forwarding references deduce (and these are special rules for forwarding references only): Lvalue function arguments deduce the template argument to a lvalue reference type and rvalue function arguments deduce it to a non-reference type. Then with the reference collapsing rules `& && -> &` and `[nothing] && -> &&`, after substitution, `auto&&`/`T&&` is a lvalue reference for lvalue argument and a rvalue reference for a rvalue argument, which is what is expected of the deduction. (There is an exception for function type arguments though.)

You'd want something like

```
json_t& operator[](auto&& index)
requires std::integral<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(index)>>
{ return std::get<array_t>(data)[index]; }
```

But since you do not actually forward `index` in the body, the forwarding reference is a bit pointless, so just

```
json_t& operator[](const std::integral auto& index)
{ return std::get<array_t>(data)[index]; }
```

would probably be fine.

Or, given that only integral types are accepted, pass-by-value is probably fine as well and potentially has better performance since integral types can typically be passed in registers without extra indirection:

```
json_t& operator[](std::integral auto index)
{ return std::get<array_t>(data)[index]; }
```

Comment: The code is part of a library, I really don't want to change it as it's not my code. I guess I can just std::move whatever value I want to use.

Comment: @Zebrafish It is a bug/mistake in the library then and should be reported.

Comment: Why does passing an lvalue int get deduced as an int reference? What does it get deduced as if I do std::move(lvalue)?